# Generate constructor with requireNonNull()

Tags: java, intellij-idea, constructor

I have a domain model with immutable classes, where most of the time the arguments are required to be non-null:

```
public class TestClass {
  private final String field;

  public TestClass(String field) {
    this.field = Objects.requireNonNull(field);
  }
}
```

I generate these constructor through *right click* -> *Generate...* -> *Constructor*:

[image: Generate Constructor]

The generated constructor, of course, haven't got the `requireNonNull()` method call, which forces me to add this for every field that needs it.

Is there any way to configure this code generation to include `requireNonNull` by default, if so, how?

A google search doesn't lead to much, but the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/generating-constructors.html), which doesn't mention anything about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to customize the constructor template, vote for the [related request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87678).